# Drupal: After installing the video module and successful set the Amazon S3 keys, how do I embed my already uploaded videos?

Tags: drupal, video, amazon-s3

I have the video module installed, with all its submodules on my Drupal 6.x site.

I have an Amazon S3 account where I have several videos already uploaded.

Those videos are private, and they were uploaded with server side encryption provided by amazon. The link to the videos starts with https://...

I´ve configured the **video filesystem** at Drupal, to use Amazon S3. I´ve set the bucket and the keys. In fact, after saving the config, the system recognizes my already uploaded files.

Now, my big question is... **how do I "paste" my already uploaded videos inside a specific (private) node??**

The module allows me to upload a new video or select one of the already uploaded ones inside my drupal installation. How do I search inside all my buckets?

Thanks!

Rosamunda